# How to combine two dictionaries an ansible by some key

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have two yaml dictionaries that i need to join between by key

```
server_groups:
  - name: grp1
    servers: server1-1,server1-2,server1-3
  - name: grp2
    servers: server2-1,server2-2,server2-3
  - name: grp3
    servers: server3-1,server3-2,server3-3

server_paths:
  - name: path1
    src: grp1
    dest: grp2
    payload: ...
  - name: path2
    src: grp3
    dest: grp1
    payload: ...
```

I want to enrich server_paths dictionary by adding src_servers and dest_servers by group name.

I tried to achieve it by such way:

```
    - set_fact:
        serverpaths: "{{ server_paths }}"
     - set_fact:
         serverpaths: "{{ serverpaths|combine({'dest_servers':server_groups| selectattr('name', 'equalto', item.dest) | map(attribute='servers') | first})}}"
       loop: "{{ server_paths }}"
```

Expected result is:

```
server_paths:
  - name: path1
    src: server1-1,server1-2,server1-3
    dest: server2-1,server2-2,server2-3
    payload: ...
  - name: path2
    src: server3-1,server3-2,server3-3
    dest: server1-1,server1-2,server1-3
    payload: ...
```

It works fine with joining but returns only last enriched element. So I'm stuck how to get all enriched elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the list *server_groups* to the dictionary *server_groups_dict*, e.g. put the expression below to the place where the lists come from

```yaml
server_groups_dict: "{{ server_groups|items2dict(key_name='name',
                                                 value_name='servers') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
server_groups_dict:
  grp1: server1-1,server1-2,server1-3
  grp2: server2-1,server2-2,server2-3
  grp3: server3-1,server3-2,server3-3
```

Now you can iterate the list *server_paths* and create the required structure, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        serverpaths: "{{ serverpaths|d([]) + [item|combine(_dict)] }}"
      loop: "{{ server_paths }}"
      vars:
        _dict: "{{ {'src': server_groups_dict[item.src],
                    'dest': server_groups_dict[item.dest]} }}"
```

gives

```yaml
serverpaths:
  - dest: server2-1,server2-2,server2-3
    name: path1
    src: server1-1,server1-2,server1-3
  - dest: server1-1,server1-2,server1-3
    name: path2
    src: server3-1,server3-2,server3-3
```

---

**Notes**

- For simplicity, I removed the attribute *payload*. The code should prevent the structure, however.

Comment: Thank you. Your advice is useful. What if server_groups would have more that one field? Of cource i can create multiple intermediate dictionaries, but it won't be elegant.

Comment: The decision to use a list for *server_groups*  is wrong. It should be a dictionary. The reasoning is simple. The values of the attribute *name* should be unique. This makes them defacto keys. As a result, you ask the wrong questions. Adding attributes to a dictionary is trivial and, if you will, also elegant. I don't understand what you mean by 'intermediate dictionaries'. Either [edit] the question or open a new one with [mre].